# Calculating accuracy for a regression tree

Tags: r, tree, rpart

I am trying to calculate the RMSE of a regression tree prediction but keep getting an error.

I have loaded a df, removed all empty records and split my df to training and validation:

```
income.df <- read.csv("adult.data.csv")

income.df$Workclass <- gsub("[?]", NA, as.character(income.df$Workclass))
income.df$Workclass <- as.factor(income.df$Workclass)
income.df$occupation <- gsub("[?]", NA, as.character(income.df$occupation))
income.df$occupation <- as.factor(income.df$occupation)
income.df$native.country <- gsub("[?]", NA, as.character(income.df$native.country))
income.df$native.country <- as.factor(income.df$native.country)

income.sub.df <- na.omit(income.df)

levels(income.sub.df$income) <- c(1,0)

names(income.sub.df)[15] <- "isBelow50k"

train.index2 <- sample(income.sub.df$Age, dim(income.sub.df)[1]*0.6)
train2.df <- income.sub.df[train.index2, ]
valid2.df <- income.sub.df[-train.index2, ]
```

Created an rpart tree

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(forecast)

tr.income <- rpart(isBelow50k ~ ., data = train2.df)
prp(tr.income)
predrpart <- predict(tr.income, newdata = valid2.df)
accuracy(predrpart, valid2.df$isBelow50k)
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Error in accuracy(predrpart, valid2.df$isBelow50k) : 
  First argument should be a forecast object or a time series.
```

I have tried converting it to a vector but nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a [classification problem, not a regression problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification). RMSE (and also the `accuracy` function from the forecast package) is not used for classification problems. Instead, I would recommend using metrics that can be derived from a [confusion matrix](http://www.dataschool.io/simple-guide-to-confusion-matrix-terminology/).

Here is one option for modifying your code to calculate a simple confusion matrix:

```
tr.income <- rpart(isBelow50k ~ ., data = train2.df)
prp(tr.income)
predrpart <- factor(ifelse(predict(tr.income, newdata = valid2.df)[,2] > .5, '>50K', '<=50K'))
table(predicted = predrpart, actual = valid2.df$isBelow50k)
```

Comment: @Avi, is this a helpful answer? Let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify.